# What is the best way to convert a currency from float to integer in Go?

Tags: go

What is the best way to convert a currency from float to integer in Go?

-------------  Added Explanation of question ----------

To expand my question a little, the following is an example of what I see as the “problem” solved by adding a rounding value of 0.004 (for 2-decimal currencies).

As far as I know, external values stored as eg. decimal, double, currency in an RDBMS need to be “imported” to Go as a float. In order to perform calculations, they then need to be converted to integer, or at least that is one method.

In the example below, fVal1 emulates an amount imported from a database. To perform calculations on it, I want to convert it to an integer. The easiest way to do that appears to me to be to add a rounding figure as illustrated.

Example code:

```
var fVal1 float64 = 19.08
var f100 float64 = 100.0
var fRound float64 = 0.004
var fResult float64 = fVal1 * f100
fmt.Printf("%f * %f as float = %f\n", fVal1, f100, fResult)
var iResult1 int64 = int64(fResult)
fmt.Printf("as Integer unrounded = %d\n", iResult1)
var iResult2 int64 = int64(fResult + fRound)
fmt.Printf("as Integer rounded = %d\n", iResult2)
```

Console output:

```
19.080000 * 100.000000 as float = 1908.000000
as Integer unrounded = 1907
as Integer rounded = 1908
```

----------- end of addition to question -----------

I’ve implemented a small package to handle multiple currencies in Go, and essentially it revolves around the following bit of code (below).

When I discovered that there were rounding errors in converting between floats and integers, the first rounding factor that I tried was 0.004 (for 2 decimals), and it appeared to work OK.

Basically, the following bit of code for currency conversion from float to int revolves around these two alternative lines of code :

```
  var iCcyAmt1 int64 = int64(fCcyBase * fScale)
  var iCcyAmt2 int64 = int64((fCcyBase + fRound) * fScale)
```

The rounding being used in “fRound” in the second alternative is “0.004”.

Running this test program (10 million iterations) results in a consistent rounding error of about 588,000 cents where the “0.004” is not added, and zero difference using the rounding figure.

Is this a safe way to handle this situation (I don’t want to use strings), or is there a better way?

Test Program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var (
        fRound      float64 = 0.004
        fScale      float64 = 100.0
        iCcyTotBase int64
        iCcyTot1    int64
        iCcyTot2    int64
    )

    const I_ITERS int = 10000000

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())

    fmt.Printf("\nTesting Float to Integer (%d iterations)"+
        " .........", I_ITERS)

    for i := 0; i < I_ITERS; i++ {
        var iCcyBase int64 = int64(999 + rand.Intn(9999999))
        var fCcyBase float64 = float64(iCcyBase) / fScale
        var iCcyAmt1 int64 = int64(fCcyBase * fScale)
        var iCcyAmt2 int64 = int64((fCcyBase + fRound) * fScale)
        iCcyTotBase += iCcyBase
        iCcyTot1 += iCcyAmt1
        iCcyTot2 += iCcyAmt2
    }

    var iCcyDiff1 int64 = iCcyTot1 - iCcyTotBase
    var iCcyDiff2 int64 = iCcyTot2 - iCcyTotBase
    fmt.Printf("\nDiff without rounding = %d\n", iCcyDiff1)
    fmt.Printf("Diff with rounding = %d\n", iCcyDiff2)
}
```

Comment: Take a look at "math/big"? That might be what you want. (Even tho I'm still not understanding your question fully)

Comment: I also do not understand your question. There are _no_ rounding errors in float manipulations in the sense that something goes wrong unpredictable. Write down what mathematical properties you expect from your "float to int" conversion. Depending on your requirements you will have to use big.Rat or may stick with float handling.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.stata.com/tag/precision/#section7 . It mentions a few things: 1. "The U.S. deficit in 2011 was $1.5 trillion. Stored as a float, this amount has a (maximum) error of ±2-24*1.5e+12 = ±$89,406.97." and 2. When precision is needed, "the currency data should be converted to integers (pennies) and stored as integers" . Obviously this is US specific, but should work for most currencies.

Comment: I have expanded my question with another example to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Comment: Actually I would never ever store money data in a float. I always use fixed point arithmetic for that. For example, if accuracy of 1 cent is enough, I'd store 123 US Dollar as 12300 (cent). Using floating point arithmetic *will* give you trouble.

Comment: topskip - Well, I don't disagree, but if the data is in an RDBMS as double or currency or decimal, how do you "import" that as integer? There is also the question as to why a float of "1908.000000" converts to an integer of "1907"?

Comment: @BrianOh while reading from the database you can convert the number you've read to integer. And for the floating point operation: the rounding "errors" are just a normal side effect of floats. See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @topskip: Accounting ledgers MUST always balance. Do you get a bank statement that's out by a cent or 2? If you deposit a check for $19.08 and get credited with $19.07 do you say - "well that's normal"?

Comment: @BrianOh of course not. That is exactly the reason why I write "don't use floats for that, use integers" If you use floats for them you will be in trouble. Where did I write otherwise?

Comment: @topskip. Ok, sorry if I misunderstood. The problem as I see it is that if we have data in an RDBMS as a double/decimal/currency we have to in some cases at least import that as a float. Maybe I'm wrong, but that's part of what I'm trying to establish. I'm importing it as a float, but maybe there's an alternative. If it has to be imported as a float, I don't see that as a major problem, it's just knowing absolutely how to handle it - which I think has been established.

Comment: This may be useful, it was just announced on /r/golang https://github.com/oguzbilgic/fpd . Fixed point decimal library.

Comment: @Intermernet: Thanks for that info, I'll take a look at it. I'm not sure that I need anything additional. I think as long as I am confident that I can convert from a double to integer, then that is all I need to know. I think that floats should be ok for interest, taxes,  etc. calculations. Interest etc. is always rounded anyway. I have considered this for quite a while and have written a small package to handle it. The package also handles formatting (which is most of it). I could be wrong, but I think that my small package is all that I need. Ints are fine for other calcs, maybe all.

Comment: FWIW, fRound of 0.00001 works for me. Maybe you only need smallest possible float. http://play.golang.org/p/1zYNRE0PJ1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to round** (as you've done).  And -as you've alluded to- the nature of floating points make this difficult, and you have to deal with some bad decimal results due to rounding errors.  AFAIK, [golang](http://golang.org/pkg/math/) doesn't have a rounding function, so you'll need to implement it.  I've seen [this gist](https://gist.github.com/indytechcook/5706434) tweeted/mentioned a few times... and it seems to have been born in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/ITZV08gAugI).

```
func RoundViaFloat(x float64, prec int) float64 {
    var rounder float64
    pow := math.Pow(10, float64(prec))
    intermed := x * pow
    _, frac := math.Modf(intermed)
    intermed += .5
    x = .5
    if frac < 0.0 {
        x=-.5
        intermed -=1
    }
    if frac >= x {
        rounder = math.Ceil(intermed)
    } else {
        rounder = math.Floor(intermed)
    }

    return rounder / pow
}
```

---

**A couple of notes/resources (for others that show up later):**

- When converting a floating point via `int64()` the fractional part
  will be discarded.
- When printing a floating point use the correct [golang format](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/).  e.g. `fmt.Printf("%.20f * %.20f as float = %.20f\n", fVal1, f100, fResult)`
- Use an Integer for money.  Avoid all of this by using pennies (and integer math in order to avoid the rounding) and divide by 100.  i.e. use a large enough fixed size integer or math/big.Int and avoid the floating point arithmetic.

*Note:* You can, alternatively, **round** using strconv (the OP wanted to avoid
   this):

```
func RoundFloat(x float64, prec int) float64 {
    frep := strconv.FormatFloat(x, 'g', prec, 64)
    f, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(frep, 64)
    return f
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the information needed viz "When converting a floating point via int64() the fractional part will be discarded." Based on that information AFAIK the following will always work when when converting a currency (allowing for different currency formats, and also allowing for negative) EG: "var fAmt float64 = 19.08; fmt.Printf("%f rounded = %d", fAmt, int64((fAmt*float64(100.0))+float64(0.5)))"

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad you got it dialed in.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that it's not possible to store an exact representation of the values you have given in a float. The `Printf()` you are doing is misleading, it is rounding the value for you. Try this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 19.08
    b := 100.0
    c := a * b
    fmt.Printf("%.20f * %.20f as float = %.20f\n", a, b, c)
}
```

Which gives:

```
19.07999999999999829470 * 100.00000000000000000000 as float = 1907.99999999999977262632
```

Now `int64()` is probably just cutting off the non-integer part of the number.

To learn more about floating point numbers see [floating-point-gui.de](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for example.

=> **Never ever try to store exact values in floating point numbers**

Comment: I'm not trying to store exact numbers in floats. I do understand how floats work. However, it is possible to convert from floats to integers if the numbers stored in the floats are simply converted from doubles, or decimals, or currencies, and essentially all one wants to do is convert them back. It's when calculations are attempted with those floats that it becomes impossible to convert back. I'm doing it in my example by adding 0.004. The example that I show does it with 10 million iterations of floats. I just want to know the best way to do it from eg. an RDBMS.

Comment: @BrianOh Perhaps your question wasn't clear enough. If you can reduce it to some small problem, you might consider deleting the text in your question and rephrase it. I am sure you can get many helpful answers here on SO, as there are quite some experts present.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The reason I posted more detail than perhaps was necessary is because I have previously been told to always post a detailed example. Perhaps I should have kept it short so that people didn't have to read a slightly lengthy explanation. Everyone has a different view on how questions should be put, and different questions require different presentation. I did think however that this would be a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a decimal class based on int64 for handling money that is handling floats, string parsing, JSON, etc.

It stores amount as 64 bit integer number of cents. Can be easily created from float or converted back to float.

Handy for storing in DB as well.

https://github.com/strongo/decimal

```
package example

import "github.com/strongo/decimal"

func Example() {
    var amount decimal.Decimal64p2; print(amount)  // 0

    amount = decimal.NewDecimal64p2(0, 43); print(amount)  // 0.43
    amount = decimal.NewDecimal64p2(1, 43); print(amount)  // 1.43
    amount = decimal.NewDecimal64p2FromFloat64(23.100001); print(amount)  // 23.10
    amount, _ = decimal.ParseDecimal64p2("2.34"); print(amount)  // 2.34
    amount, _ = decimal.ParseDecimal64p2("-3.42"); print(amount)  // -3.42
}
```

Works well for my debts tracker app https://debtstracker.io/